# detect memory leak in visual studio c++ between two lines

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, memory-leaks

I would like to detect memory leaks in visual studio c++. But instead of checking the whole solution, I would like to check for memory leaks between two code lines or a function. I don't want to check for memory leaks in the whole solution. For example:

```
// some code
startMemoryLeakDetection()
// other code
stopAndReportMemoryLeakDetection()
// some other code
```

Can anyone guide me to the necessary tools / programs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can identify memory leak by using CRT dump and also using memory state comparison to get the statistics.
Please refer steps given in MSDN for more details

```
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &s1 );
// memory allocations take place here
_CrtMemCheckpoint( &s2 );

if ( _CrtMemDifference( &s3, &s1, &s2) )
   _CrtMemDumpStatistics( &s3 );
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: Just be careful if other threads are running, or if the code between the checkpoints hits singletons or other global variables and alters the amount of heap memory they hold. Either of those things can cause false positives.

Comment: Note: You're missing a _ at the start of the codeblock.